# setInterval continue running after return statement

Tags: javascript

a simple function has a setInterval function internally
why setInterval continue running even after function has complete return statement

```
function test(){
  setInterval(()=>{
    console.log(1)
  },1000)

  console.log('end')
  return 0;
}


test() //output: end 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: It is setInterval is callback function and if you want to remove it. You need to clear it with clearInterval.

Comment: *internally* - absolutely not. JavaScript runs on a single thread and these timer callbacks can't run until the containing function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval(function, t ) is a webapi for calling a callback function after every t milliseconds. So that's the reason why it's running continuously.

Comment: hi raj240,  so webapi is not controlled by javascript, but still I have mix webapi with javascript ?  To me, it feels like this setInterval is not controlled by js functions. But why I can nested this API in javascript function. Isn't it a property(method) on window object following ES standard ?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval evaluates your expression every Xms and needs to be clearead by clearInterval if you want it to stop.

What you are looking for is setTimeout which will run it only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re goal is that the function will run one time after X sec/ms, you probably want to use setTimeout() function.
If you’re goal is to run a function every X sec/ms and to stop after X sec/ms, you can put a condition right before the setInterval() function.